# How can I check whether a String is purely letters?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I want to run a validation check on a JTextField to ensure that it contains only letters. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Also look at [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) & [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
str.matches("\\p{Alpha}+")
```

Note that `\p{Alpha}` matches any letter (`a-z` or `A-Z`), and hence `\p{Alpha}+` matches any continuous string of letters.

Comment: This seems very concise and therefore perfect for my needs. Where can I learn more about that "\\p{Aplha}+" syntax so that I can understand what it all actually means? I could just copy and paste but I would then not really be able to learn.

Comment: @Mike The documentation for the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class contains some specific information, but you might want to look up a tutorial on "regular expressions".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean containsOnlyLetters(String s)
{
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
    {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```